# can rename column size to filesize cause problem in attachment_fu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment-fu

can I rename the columns with attachment_fu ?

I am using oracle as my database and size is keyword in oracle. so i don't want to create a column with size name. So is it ok to create a column with filesize instead of size while using attachment_fu ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using filesize, just add the following method to the class having the attachment.

```
  def size 
    self.filesize 
  end

  def size=(bytes) 
    self.filesize = bytes 
  end
```

which should solve your problem , without hacking into attachment_fu.